# In automic how to communicate between the job in workflow?

Tags: automic

As we know that one job can call in multiple workflow. 
I need an variable which give me the workflow name at time of runtime so that I can write this information in log.
It should **not** be global variable. it **must** be define with in the scope of workflow.

Answer (score 0):

In the process tab - where I assume your code is and where you need the parent object (workflow in your case) - you can click on the "Variables..." menu item.

In the popped up variable picker you need to change to "Object" for "Category" and pick "Processor (name)".

This will provide the name of the superordinate (fancy word for parent) object - in your case the Workflow. Also available would be "Processor (RunID)" providing the ID.

This will insert the "system-variable" &$PROCESSOR#, which holds the name of the parent object or you simple copy that variable from my answer :)